# When does Method.invoke retrieve the vtable method pointer in Java

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I am reading the book "The Well Grounded Java Developer 2nd edition", and in chapter 17 (Modern internals) there is a description of how the reflection internals work. First the duality of the Entry vs Entry.class is discussed (the first picture), which shows how the array of Methods from the Class will match the ordering (indexing) as the ones from the klassOop for the actual type. Following that, in the second screenshot, we are shown a DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl whose role is to delegate the actual invocation to the native or custom method accessor.

When and how is the bytecode for the method to be executed retrieved from the klassOop by the MethodAccessor's invocation.  I guess the Method.slot field used, but from the available code, I don't see exactly how, but I suspect it's some native call which may read it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why does the second picture assume that the `Entry` object has references to `Method` objects? This is still the same kind of object as in the left half of the first image. The object doesn’t change when you create `Method` objects. Further, there is no need for a generated `MethodAccessorImpl` object to have a special way to access bytecode. It is encapsulating an invocation that does exactly the same thing as in the left half of the first image.

Comment: I think there has been a typo in the second picture (in the book). I think it should be an Entry.class